# %0D%0A not creating a newline when echo is called

Tags: php

Every time I try to echo a string there is no new line. I how can I make a newline when calling echo in php using the `$_GET`?

here is my code:

```
<?php
    $text = "Hello world";
    $text2 = $_GET['msg'];

    echo $text2
?>
```

and this is what I enter in the url:

```
http://localhost/hello.php?msg=hello%0Dworld
```

or this one:

```
http://localhost/hello.php?msg=hello%0Aworld
```

and even this one:

```
http://localhost/hello.php?msg=hello%0D%0Aworld
```

The echo has to be a newline please don't say I should use a different method than `$_GET`. It has to be `$_GET`

Comment: The key word is **HTML**

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not very good with web development. I was creating this php for a mobile app. A better explanation will be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While performing your exercises you are creating an HTML page.

HTML is a special markup language, which renders according to set of rules, some of them are:

- `<>` characters has a special meaning of control structures named *tags*
- **all newline characters are ignored**
- to make a newline on the page, one have to use suitable tag - such as `<br>`, `<p>` or whatever.

So, to make a newline appear on your page, you have to convert newline characters to tags. Either use `nl2br()` function to get a `<br />` tag or `str_replace()` if you want any other one

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that echoing any request variables without validating them is a considerable security risk! If you want to publish any application with this code it needs to be redesigned.

As *common sense* states, the conversion from urlencoded to the corresponding character is automatically done by php, but HTML does not render such characters, so you either need to convert them into linebreaks or enclose the message in `<pre>` tags.

Comment: PHP performs such decoding automatically on $_GET variables

Comment: My common sense tells me I've made a mistake and need to edit my answer.